Docker de Proyecto laravel con multitenancy
Cree un proyecto el laravel pero no funciona el Docker ya lo probe en XAMPP y funciona bien pero a la hora de probarlo en Docker las rutas me arojan 404 que podría ser?
dockerfile


# Usar la imagen oficial de PHP con Apache
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Establecer el directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Instalar extensiones de PHP y herramientas necesarias
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Instalar Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copiar los archivos del proyecto al contenedor
COPY . .

# Establecer el directorio de documentos de Apache
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public

# Configurar Apache para que use el directorio de documentos correcto
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf \
    && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Establecer las variables de entorno necesarias para Composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

# Instalar dependencias de Composer
RUN composer install

# Dar permisos a la carpeta de almacenamiento y caché
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Exponer el puerto 80
EXPOSE 80



Docker compose:


version: '4'

services:
  app:
    container_name: App_laravel
    image: davidch244/laravel_emlaze:Comunidad
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: mysql_emlaze
    image: mysql:8.0.36
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: emlaze6290#
      MYSQL_USER: genoma
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: emlaze6290#
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

volumes:
  dbdata:



Esta seria la configuracion del docker compose con la cual me estoy guiando ya modifique las configuraciones del apache2 montándolo en 1 volumen pero parece que no es por esa zona algúna recomendación, si se requiere mas info con gusto la facilito.
esta es la config del apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias demo.localhost

<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

con esa config tengo el apache del resto son configuraciones predeterminadas.

hola, compartenos tus archivos de configuracion de apache para ver con que configuracion queda el apache. Por ahora te puedo decir que la declaracion del servicio app en docker-composer.yaml esta ok.

agregado e intentado varias combinaciones pero no doy con el chiste
